# scrollsToTop not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have the following object structure:

- UITabBarController

  - UINavigationController

    - UITableViewController

It used to work, but then I added the UITabBarController into the mix and made a bunch of other large changes and somewhere in between it stopped.

So far I have:

- created a new project with that structure, and that seems to work OK.
- checked that there's only one view with scrollsToTop
- tried adding a new UITableViewController directly under UITabBarController... still doesn't work.

One thing that might be of use is that `-scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:` isn't even being called, even though the table view controller's `tableView.delegate` is set to the controller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just came across this problem myself.

If, like me, you started from the tab bar template Apple provides, then you have to add the following line to applicationDidFinishLaunching: in your app delegate:

```
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This one line is what fixed it for me.

Comment: Fabulous! Just what the doctor ordered!

Comment: Thanks! I went from storyboards to MainWindow.xib and this fixed my scroll to top not working too.

Answer (score 1):

I added following line to UITableViewController.

```
[self.navigationController.parentViewController.view.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: If you have to hack things like this, there is a clear sign, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I think your right, I think this will not work at the current iOS version.