# Scrolling all scrollviews to the top when statusbar is tapped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've 3 tableviews in my view and I want to enable scroll to top feature for all tables at the same time, i.e., if the user taps on status bar all the three tables should be scrolled to top position.

I've tried using scrollsToTop property of all my tableViews and also various combinations of YES/No for this property. for example

```
table1.scrollsToTop = YES;
table2.scrollsToTop = NO;
table3.scrollsToTop = NO;
```

but not able to achieve this. Do we have any way out to get the event of tap on status bar so that I may try to set the content offset of all the tables to top position or any other work around.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you checked the question http://stackoverflow.com/q/1063213/859742

Comment: Solved this problem by overriding scrollViewShouldScrollToTop method like below,




`- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    [table1 scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    [table2 scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    [table3 scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];


    return NO;
}`

Comment: MPG if possible, answer your own question and accept your answer so this question is marked "answered". Thanks!

Comment: @Kalle newbie in stackoverflow...doing that

Comment: We're all new ones. I only told you as I kept ending up here when I was browsing questions. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this problem by overriding scrollViewShouldScrollToTop method like below, -

```
- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView { 
  [table1 scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
  [table2 scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
  [table3 scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

  return NO;
}
```